# checking for elements in rows and columns of lists of lists without using pandas

Tags: python, list, iterator

If I have a list of lists

matrix =  [[2, 3, 1, 2],[1, 2, 3, 2],[3, 3, 1, 2], [2, 2, 3, 3]]

how can I check with a for loop if for example element = 1 is present in each column

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy:

```
np.any(a==1, 1).all()
```

---

```
>>> a = np.array([[2, 3, 1, 2],[1, 2, 3, 2],[3, 3, 1, 2], [2, 2, 3, 3]])
>>> np.any(a==1, 1).all()
False
>>> a = np.array([[2, 3, 1, 2],[1, 2, 3, 2],[3, 3, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3, 3]])
>>> np.any(a==1, 1).all()
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#all), `in` and a list comprehension:

```py
matrix = [[2, 3, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 2], [3, 3, 1, 2], [2, 2, 3, 3]]

valid = all(1 in row for row in matrix)
```

---

Or, the verbose way:

```py
matrix = [[2, 3, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 2], [3, 3, 1, 2], [2, 2, 3, 3]]

valid = True
for row in matrix:
    if 1 not in row:
        valid = False
        break
```

Comment: No need for the brackets. You're creating a list then evaluating `all` on it. Just let `all` evaluate a generator comprehension. It will be less expensive depending on the values.